# Using a resource created in one cdk construct in another construct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I'm building the infrastructure for an application using AWS-CDK.

I have a construct that builds multiple S3 buckets and another construct that creates a lambda function that fetches data from these buckets.

In order to be able to give my lambda permissions to fetch data from the bucket I need the buckets ARN.

Is there a way in which I could export the bucket arn from the construct that produces the buckets and import it into the lambda construct?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, maybe something like this:

```js
export class ConsumingStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const producingStack = new BucketProducingStack(this, 'BucketProducingStack');
    const { bucket1, bucket2 } = producingStack;
    //Create new lambda stack here
    //const lambdaStack = new LambdaStack(this, { bucket1, bucket2} );
  }
}

export class BucketProducingStack extends cdk.NestedStack {
  bucket1: string;
  bucket2: string; 

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.NestedStackProps) {
    const bucket1 = new Bucket(this, 'BucketOne');
    const bucket2 = new Bucket(this, 'BucketTwo');
    this.bucket1 = bucket1.bucketArn;
    this.bucket2 = bucket2.bucketArn;
  }
}
```

No guarantee this compiles as it was written entirely in this window, but hopefully conveys the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python, you can add

```
    @property
def main_source_bucket(self) -> _s3.IBucket:
    return self.bucket
```

Reference it in your app stack like this ..

```
bucket = S3Construct(self, "bucket", "bucket1")        
LambdaConstruct(self, "lambda1", "dev", bucket.main_source_bucket
```